# Force citation to include name initial to remove ambiguity (Bernoulli family problem)

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm writing a paper that needs citation of work of **Daniel** Bernoulli (not Jacob Bernoulli). I find citing his work as (Bernoulli 1742) insufficient.

Journal requires using `natbib` for managing citattions. I'm guessing there is some magic that can be done in the `.bib` file to fix this. Relevant entry currently stands as:

```
@Article{Bernoulli:1742,
    author = {D. Bernoulli},
    title = {The 26th letter to Euler},
    journal = {Correspondence Mathematique et Physique},
    year = {1742},
    volume = {2},
    number = {}, 
    pages = {},
    month = {},
    note = {},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the author in two `{{}}`. In this way it is not treated as first and last name. To preserve correct sorting you could use the `\noopsort{}` trick as suggested by @vonbrand.

```
@PREAMBLE{ {\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}} }
@article{Bernoulli:1742,
    author = {{\noopsort{Bernoulli, Daniel}}{D. Bernoulli}},
    title = {The 26th letter to Euler},
    journal = {Correspondence Mathematique et Physique},
    year = {1742},
    volume = {2},
    number = {},
    pages = {},
    month = {},
    note = {},
}
```

Comment: But that will screw up sorting... use the `\noopsort{}` trick to sort as e.g. `Bernoulli, Daniel`.

Comment: @vonbrand Thanks for pointing this out. I updated the answer.

Comment: Looking again, this is more InCollection or Misc than Article (just too bad no @ is allowed...).

Comment: Yes, `@incollection` would fit better.