# biblatex - Family name + initial for everyone, but full given name for ambiguous entries

Tags: biblatex

I am compiling a large bibliography with `biblatex` (3.16) and am struggling with the `uniquename` feature as applied to initials and full names. (The question is limited to the format *of the bibliography*, since the document consistently uses `\nocite`.)

I cite authors as "Family, G." (and other roles as "G. Family"), where "G." is the abbreviated given name. (Since prefixes play a role too, I am including the relevant code in my MWE.) Individuals sharing a last name *and an initial* require separate treatment, though, as "Family, G." becomes ambiguous.

This is the [the notorious Bernoulli brothers problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532976) (though that question dealt with `bibtex` not `biblatex`). To identify Jacob and Johann Bernoulli, I need to use their full given names.

I feel that there has to be an option to take care of this automatically, but so far, I couldn't get any of the approaches in the documentation to work. If I execute option `giveninits`, this abbreviates all given names. But then, it also seems to deactivate the function of `uniquename`, and the two *J. Bernoulli*'s become indistinguishable.
With `uniquename=full` (or similar values) and without `giveninits`, however, all names appear unabbreviated, regardless of disambiguation. And [this elegant answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352750) did not work for me.

I would like to avoid **workarounds**, such as (1) enclosing the names in braces: `{Bernoulli, Johann}` (which by the way needs to be inverted to `{Johann Bernoulli}` depending on the role), or (2) fully committing to `giveinits` and inputing the unwieldy `author = {family=Bernoulli, given=Johann, given-i={Johann\nopunct}}`. These workarounds function on a case-by-case, entry-by-entry basis, do not cover potential new ambiguities when adding new entries, they are error-prone in a large bibliography.

I'm hoping for a **general solution** that should ideally:

- abbreviate given initials as "G." in the bibliography, unless the initial "G." is common to distinct individuals, then output "Given".
- be able to scan across different namelists for doubles: say one of the Bernoullis is "author", another "translator" or some other *custom* roles that we may employ (f.i. we use "correspondent" in a custom entrytype `letter`).

Here is my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{uniquename.bib}
@book{translator-jac-bernoulli,
    author = {de Andrade, Mário},
    title = {A book translated by Jacob Bernoulli},
    translator = {Bernoulli, Jacob}}

@book{book-daniel-bernoulli,
    author = {Bernoulli, Daniel},
    title = {A book by Daniel Bernoulli}}

@collection{editor-joh-bernoulli,
    editor = {Bernoulli, Johann},
    title = {A collection edited by Johann Bernoulli}}

@book{book-jac-Bernoulli,
    author = {Bernoulli, Jacob},
    title = {A book by Jacob Bernoulli}}

@book{book-joh-bernoulli,
    author = {Bernoulli, Johann},
    title = {A book by Johann Bernoulli}}
\end{filecontents}{uniquename.bib}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[%
style=numeric,
giveninits,     % the desired look, though incompatible with uniquename
%uniquename=full,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{useprefix=true}
\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate{
  \keypart{\namepart{family}}
  \keypart{\namepart{prefix}}
  \keypart{\namepart{given}}
  \keypart{\namepart{suffix}}}

\addbibresource{uniquename.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a new name format for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[%
style=numeric,
uniquename=full,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{always-init}{%
\ifnumequal{\value{uniquename}}{2}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}



\DeclareNameAlias{author}{always-init}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{always-init}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{useprefix=true}
\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate{
  \keypart{\namepart{family}}
  \keypart{\namepart{prefix}}
  \keypart{\namepart{given}}
  \keypart{\namepart{suffix}}}

\addbibresource{uniquename.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]